# MySQL more columns then in php query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I changed to another database with more columns. Nut now my register page doesn't work anymore. The tables all have default settings.
How can I let the query put all the data in the columns and use the defaults for other columns?

This is my query:

```
    mysql_query("

    INSERT INTO `users` 
    (`username`, `password`, `mail`, 'account_created', 'ip_last', 'ip_reg')
     VALUES(
            '".$naam."', '".$wachtwoord."', '".$email."', 
            '".$timestamp."', '".$ip."', '".$ip."'
           )
     ");
```

It worked before, but now on this new database it doesn't work anymore. I didn't change my php version or something.

Comment: Get rig off single quotes on the column names `'account_created', 'ip_last', 'ip_reg'`

Comment: Now see PHP's modern APIs (PDO/mysqli_) and, crucially, their use of prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables in query strings without quotes.
By the way you should think about more secure -
[PDO? What is this magic system](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php)

PDO Version:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, password, mail, account_created, ip_last, ip_reg) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$query->execute(array($naam, $wachtwoord, $email, $timestamp, $ip, $ip));
```

Trash Version:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username, password, mail, account_created, ip_last, ip_reg) VALUES ($naam, $wachtwoord, $email, $timestamp, $ip, $ip)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Know the difference between **back ticks** and **single quotes**

```
 mysql_query("
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `mail`, `account_created`, `ip_last`, `ip_reg`) VALUES('".$naam."', '".$wachtwoord."', '".$email."', '".$timestamp."', '".$ip."', '".$ip."')");
```